# How to Refrence the Next Comment in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, timestamp, comments

By "next comment in Wordpress" I don't mean pagination buttons to go to the next page.  And I'm not asking about allowing readers to subscribe to follow-on comments.  What I'm asking is this:

How can I reference comment N+1 when defining what to display for comment N?  Specifically, I want to get the timestamp for the approved comment immediately following the comment in question.

I've been searching online for an answer, but if there are any answers they're buried under results for the "Next" pagination button or suscribing to later comments.

Maybe this can be done somehow with wp_comment_query():

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query

But I've never used that before.  In fact, my PHP and WordPress experience pretty much begins and ends with the site I'm working on customizing, which is my first web design project.

What's the simplest way to tackle this?  Here's why I want to know, by the way:

On my site, I'm showing 2 timestamps when a comment has been delayed in the moderation queue – 1 timestamp for the moment the comment was submitted and a later timestamp for the moment when the comment was approved and published.  But I'm trying to control the situations in which this second time stamp is displayed.  1 criterion, which I've already implemented, is based on a threshold time delay.  But it also matters if the NEXT comment was published before the comment above it was approved.  In that case, I want to show the 2nd time stamp to clarify the fact that the comment underneath was written without having seen the comment in question.

Comment: So - if we answer *this question* - about how to get the data, and reference it - is that a "complete" answer to you? Or are you also wondering how to get this into your template, etc?

Comment: Which theme are you using? Are you looking to do this in a new template? Or, modify an existing template? Are you familiar with [wp_list_comments](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem, but it took me awhile.  All sorts of simple approaches had to be discarded for one reason or another.  Ultimately I had to use wp_comment_query.

This sort of thing would be very intuitive as a MySQL query (which is the language most familiar to me):

select `timestamp` from `some table`
where `timestamp` > 
    (
    select `timestamp` from `some table`
    where `comment id` = This_Comment_ID
    )
    as `some alias`
and `comment id` > This_Comment_ID
order by `time stamp` asc
limit 1;

But WordPress throws up all sorts of barriers.  For 1 thing, a WordPress date_query allows an "after" definition with respect to dates ... but not times.  So we can't use that.  Instead, the " `timestamp` > " portion has to be written this way:

```
'date_query' => array(
        'year'  => date( 'Y' , strtotime( $written_stamp ) ) ,
        'month' => date( 'F' , strtotime( $written_stamp ) ) ,
        'day'   => date( 'j' , strtotime( $written_stamp ) ) ,
        'hour' => date( 'H' , strtotime( $written_stamp ) ) ,
        'minute'=> date( 'i' , strtotime( $written_stamp ) ) ,
        'compare' => '>='
    ),
```

where $written_stamp is the moment when the comment was submitted.  Even that timestamp has to be concatenated from get_comment_date() plus get_comment_time().

To make matters worse, Wordpress's query doesn't allow comparisons with comment IDs.  I can't simply write " `comment id` > This_Comment_ID ".  It's not enough to look for comments with time stamps >= the current comment's time stamp.  Because that would include the current comment – possibly others as well, if more than 1 comment was submitted during the same minute.  So to break ties and exclude comments which are in fact earlier, I was obliged to add some very inelegant lines to the wordpress query, specifically exluding the half dozen most recent comments up to and including the comment in question:

```
    'comment__not_in' => array(
            $this_comment ,
            $this_comment - 1 ,
            $this_comment - 2 ,
            $this_comment - 3 ,
            $this_comment - 4 ,
            $this_comment - 5
            )
```

where $this_comment = get_comment_id().

Then, it seems the WordPress query is designed to return a whole bunch of comments in the array – not just 1 piece of information for 1 comment, which is what I need.  So I went through a foreach anyway because that's what's expected, apparently.

Simple code.  But unnecessarily difficult to come up with.